# Can a static function of a class access global static varaibles?

Tags: c++, variables, static, global

```
/*In header file */
class abc{
public:
static bool do_something();

}

/*In other file */
static bool isvalid=false; //global variable

bool abc::do_something()
{
return isValid;
}
```

it is compiling fine.I want to know is it correct to use ?

Comment: It's legal C++. Whether or not it's "correct" depends on what one considers correct when asking.

Comment: It's legal to use, certainly.

Comment: Yes it's technically correct, but probably bad design.

Comment: Generally global variables are a bad plan, so hopefully there's another way to accommodate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is correct - there will be no symbol for isvalid, and other files will not be able to see it.  They can read it's current value by calling `abc::do_something()`

The member function does not need to be static.  All instances will be able to return the same current value of `isValid`

The normal way of hiding data in C++ is to make it private and static in the class...

header file

```
class abc{
    static bool isValid;  // can be seen, does not use space in an instance
public:
    static bool do_something();

}


/*In other file */
bool abc::isvalid=false; //global variable

bool abc::do_something()
{
    return isValid;
}
```